# Unable to delete UIManagedDocument using NSFileCoordinator

Tags: ios, core-data, icloud, uimanageddocument, nsfilecoordinator

I've modified Apple's Lister sample to work with `UIManagedDocument` instead of `UIDocument`. Everything works except for deleting a document. When I attempt to delete a document using Apple's code in the `removeListAtURL` method in [ListUtilites.swift](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/Lister/Listings/Swift_ListerKit_ListUtilities_swift.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014701-Swift_ListerKit_ListUtilities_swift-DontLinkElementID_161) which uses the `NSFileCoordinator` I get this error message after the listed document disappears then reappears in the simulator:

```
CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:file:///Users/.../AppGroup/E16FD6E8-8AD6-44BB-A031-5FB497F04FD4/Documents/myList.list/StoreContent/persistentStore options:{
    NSPersistentStoreRemoveStoreOnCleanupKey = 1;
} ... returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134080 "(null)" UserInfo={NSUnderlyingException=Can't add the same store twice} with userInfo dictionary {
    NSUnderlyingException = "Can't add the same store twice";
```

The "Can't add the same store twice" error doesn't make any sense to me since I'm deleting the file. Perhaps I need to close the file first? The file is local and not in iCloud so I don't think I need to delete any transaction logs. Also when I remove the `NSFileCoordinator` code it works fine just user `NSFileManager` right away it works fine for local files but I get the same error for iCloud files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot to close the document first. Remember kids, always close your documents before deleting them... especially `UIManagedDocument`s.